# How does contemporary analytic philosophy reply to the late Wittgenstein's injunction against theory?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, metaphilosophy, wittgenstein, analytic-philosophy, contemporary-philosophy

In the [In Our Time episode on Wittgenstein](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p0054945) philosopher [Ray Monk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Monk) says the following:

> It's a central view of the later Wittgenstein that there can be no such thing as a philosophical theory. I think most analytic philosophers nowadays regards themselves as engaged in precisely the kind of philosophical theory the kind of which Wittgenstein denied.

If Monk is not wrong (perhaps he is), then how do "most analytic philosophers nowadays" reply to Wittgenstein's denial of the possibility, value, and/or meaning of the philosophical theorizing they engage in? On what grounds, contrary to Wittgenstein, do they believe that their theories are meaningful?

I hope to understand how current analytic philosophers, taking Wittgenstein into consideration, give a new account of how the late Wittgenstein is in fact wrong, arguing that it is indeed possible to do meaningful theoretical work in philosophy, including, for example, the work analytic philosophy has produced in the past 10 or so years.

Comment: Many did not feel the need to reply even in the 50s, late Wittgenstein's "therapeutic positivism" was derided and characterized as a hyped fad. And Grice's separation of semantics and pragmatics was seen as taking care of Wittgenstein's arguments in favor of "no theory" language games, see [IEP The Demise of Ordinary Language Philosophy](https://www.iep.utm.edu/ord-lang/#H5). Here is a typical current attitude as expressed on the [young philosophers' blog](https://philosopherscocoon.typepad.com/blog/2013/06/philosophical-fads-and-the-sociology-of-the-profession.html)

Comment: For a comprehensive historical survey see  Criticisms of Wittgenstein and The Aftermath in [Hacker's book Wittgenstein's Place in the 20th Century Analytic Philosophy](http://pdfhumanidades.com/sites/default/files/apuntes/Hacker%2C%20P.M.S.%20-%20Wittgenstein%E2%80%99s%20place%20in%20twentieth-century%20analytic%20philosophy-Blackwell%20%281996%29.pdf). For a more sympathetic recent take see [Azzouni, The Rule-Following Paradox and its Implications for Metaphysics](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319490601).

Comment: Basically all Wittgenstein is saying is that he cannot understand metaphysics and has no theory.

Comment: @Conifold: Indeed. Sadly, there are as many if not more fads today.

Comment: Analytical philosophers of today represent a tribe the members of which gather around the totem pole murmuring a language that only they can use during their passtime conversation called "rational argumentation".Their primordial concern is to make a living out of these nonsensical utterances and their low self esteem enhances the urge towards a "unified theory of philosophy".Quantum mechanics is as much alien to lay people as analytic philosophy is and yet the former proves itself time and again even to lay people whereas philosophy displays a grotesque feature of human mind.

Comment: @PeterJ — That's a particularly jaundiced misrepresentation of what Wittgenstein was after, don't you think?

Comment: @Ted - It's a bit brutal, but clearly correct. The 'Investigations' are a sorry affair. But in his defence the same comment goes for the modern philosophy department.

Comment: @PeterJ — Well, I have to disagree with that. The PI suffers from underdevelopment (particularly towards the end), but it's an acute work. An uncomfortable work for anyone who follows the analytic philosophy paradigm, but acute nonetheless. We'll have to debate that somewhere else, of course, but I don't think it's wise for you to dismiss W quite that baldly. (of course, it doesn't help that this question misrepresents W's therapy in the first place...)

Comment: @TedWrigley how you think the q misunderstands W? It's not an expression of my own views. Just trying to better understand, since I don't think the PI has been well-refuted.

Comment: @MaxWallace — Eh, I'm going to have to write an answer to the question if you want me to get into that. It's too long for a comment. Give me a bit to get to that.

Comment: What's interesting is that Wittgenstein's insights from the PI have now been re-integrated into epistemology as a philosophical theory. See: hinge epistemology for example, which has built a cottage industry of theory out of one line of the PI.

Comment: @TedWrigley No point in us arguing, but I read the PI in amazement at the lack of substance. He doesn't; even seem well informed. Goes to show that we all come at these things differently.   .

Comment: @PeterJ: Since I don't know what you were expecting (i.e., what you mean by 'substance'), I can't really comment on this. One man might complain about a McDonald's hamburger because it isn't filet mignon, another man might complain about filet mignon because it isn't a McDonald's hamburger. It's doubtful those two complaints are equivalent, but until I'm sure which one you're making... <shrug>

Comment: @TedWrigley - Did W solve even one problem? Did he claim to understand metaphysics? Has he had any impact on philosophy? If so, why has it not changed since the days of Plato? I feel the facts speak for themselves.

Comment: @PeterJ: (1) Yes, as much as any philosopher ever did. (2) No, but he contributed a lot to its understanding. (3) Yes, obviously; I'm not even sure why you'd ask that. Philosophy has changed an awful lot since the days of Plato, so I really can't fathom your perspective at all. Are you still a proponent of Ideal Forms? I'm guessing you're in that modern 'sciencey' school that's left over from the heyday of Analytical Philosophy, and that's fine, but don't be one of those people that turns it into a prejudice.

Comment: @ PeterJ and TedWrigley if you two want to continue please take this discussion elsewhere. You aren't going to resolve your disagreement or convince anyone in the comments section of my question. Also, please consider making an effort to give others the benefit of the doubt and assume best intentions (no ad hominems). This helps make the community more pleasant and welcoming for everyone.

Comment: @MaxWallace _ Point taken. But I sometimes think disagreements revealed in the comments can shed light on the question.